# Python Empty Iterable as Default Parameter

Tags: python, default-value, iterable

In this method, I understand why not to use the empty list:

```
  def some_method(self,a,b=[]):
      for x in b:
          etc...
```

And I understand that the recommended pattern is to do this:

```
  def some_method(self,a,b=None):
      b = b or []
      for x in b:
          etc...
```

But, for a method where b is very explicitly a read-only value, why not use this (an empty tuple):

```
  def some_method(self,a,b=()):
      for x in b:
          etc...
```

It seems cleaner to me in this case. Am I wrong?

Comment: Looks good to me. Any reference to a source that says *not* to do it the way you've shown?

Comment: I feel the two communicate something slightly different. `b=None` is saying "`b` is an optional parameter, do a different behavior  since I didn't specify `b`". The other one is, "do the expected behavior to this list, that happens to be empty".

Comment: I'm with you on this one. "Special cases aren't special enough". Any default you assign is already communicating "optional parameter".

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Nothing explicitly saying not to... But in all the things I've read about default lists, no one ever suggested other than my second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tuple technique should work, though it's uncommon. It's also worth noting that, if you truly are not writing to `b`, having it be a list shouldn't hurt you either.

The only (nitpicky) objection I might muster is that (in my view at least) semantically, tuples are ideally more like records (think datetime structs) than homogeneous sequences of values.

I also agree with michaelb above that the semantics of "empty sequence" and None are different.